# Unable to create Azure B2C User Flow via powershell with b2cIdentityUserFlow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a user flow with PowerShell, but I receive`The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`. I was reading the documentation from Microsoft but with no success.

```
  Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "myorg.onmicrosoft.com"


  $managementAccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId "$tenantId" -ResourceTypeName MSGraph
  $DefinitionFilePath = "C:\azdeploy\flows\b2csignin.json"
  $signinFlowContent = Get-Content $DefinitionFilePath

  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows" `
    -Method "POST" `
    -Headers @{
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
      "Authorization" = "Bearer $($managementAccessToken.Token)";
    } `
    -Body $signinFlowContent
```

JSON Content(Default From Microsoft Docs):

```
{
    "id": "Customer",
    "userFlowType": "signUpOrSignIn",
    "userFlowTypeVersion": 3
}
```

Connect-AzAccount is made with a user who is Global Administrator, also tried with  Lifecycle Workflows Administrator permissions. I don't know what to do, trying the old API but it is deprecated. I need to create a few User Flows with а few Application Claims. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one **json file** with same parameters as you like below:

[image]

I have one user named **`Sritest`** having **Global Administrator** role like below:

[image]

When I ran the same code as you by signing in with above user, I got **same error** as below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "myorg.onmicrosoft.com"

$managementAccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -TenantId "$tenantId" -ResourceTypeName MSGraph
$DefinitionFilePath = "C:\test\b2csignin.json"
$signinFlowContent = Get-Content $DefinitionFilePath

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows" `
    -Method "POST" `
    -Headers @{
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
      "Authorization" = "Bearer $($managementAccessToken.Token)";
    } `
    -Body $signinFlowContent
```

**Response:**

[image]

You need to have `IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All` permission to create userflow.

To **resolve** the error, I registered one Azure AD application and added that API permission like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent**    after adding API permissions in application. Now, I created one **client secret** and added all these details in getting access token by modifying PowerShell code.

When I ran below **modified** code, userflow created successfully as below:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "c6d99123-0cf9-4b64-bde3-xxxxxxxxx"

$graphtokenBody = @{   
   grant_type    = "client_credentials"   
   scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"   
   client_id     = "appID"   
   client_secret = "secret"
}  
    
$graphToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/c6d99123-0cf9-4b64-bde3-xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $graphtokenBody 
$token = $graphToken.access_token

$DefinitionFilePath = "C:\test\b2csignin.json"
$signinFlowContent = Get-Content $DefinitionFilePath

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows" `
    -Method "POST" `
    -Headers @{
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
      "Authorization" = "Bearer $($token)";
    } `
    -Body $signinFlowContent
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where `B2C_1_Customer` **userflow** is present like below:

[image]

Comment: It works, as well. Can I add Application Claims in that JSON for example to add Display Name or Surname?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to add **application claims** via Graph API. You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/798406/add-application-claims-for-signin-flow-with-micros).

Comment: Hmm, I saw that it was from about 10 months ago, is it fixed now? I will try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/b2cidentityuserflow-post-userattributeassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)